# How to count row faster with mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to count total buyer from `uid` if no one buy display `0`. As well as `zbuy` for total buy. When I include this in the query - `ifnull(count(distinct b.uid),0)as zuid`. The processing time increase to 14s comparing to 0.001 without it.

So, is there any method to calculate these vars faster without include in the query? I'm not so good with mysql so I don't know much option beside this.

```
select  t.*,
        t.hdate, t.title,
        ifnull(count(distinct b.uid),0) as zuid, 
        ifnull(sum(b.buy),0) as zbuy 
from product_today t
    left join product_today_buy b on b.hid=t.hid
where date(t.dtime)=?
group by t.sid
order by t.dtime desc
```

While `product_today` is the list of product selling on that day. Which store product title and quantity. The `product_today_buy` with store the order from customer. That will compare the stock of each product from `product_today`.

There are 2 columns that I want to include in the table - `zuid` and `zbuy`. Both columns are calculated from data of both tables.

Comment: What's your explain from your query and indexes?

Comment: Did you need to `select t.*`?  Your query seems to make no sense because the aggregate function and `group by` column can't match

Comment: Yes I need `t.*` otherwise the column I want to show will be undefined index. As well as `group by t.sid` - this will generate each product from `product_today`.

Answer (score 0):

The first performance red flag is

```
where date(t.dtime)=?
```

That is not "sargable"; change it to

```
WHERE t.dtime >= ?
  AND t.dtime  < ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(and supply the date twice when binding)

Then have this index on `product_today`:

```
INDEX(dtime)
```

This may be improper:

```
SELECT t.* ... group by t.sid
```

It is proper only if all the other columns in `t` depend on `sid`.  That would imply that `sid` is the `PRIMARY KEY`; is it?  Please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE t;
```

Hmmm...

```
select  t.*,
        t.hdate, t.title,
```

That delivers `hdate` and `title` twice.  Did you really want that?

For `b`, have

```
INDEX(hid, uid, buy)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't fully understand what you say but I'll try to. Will let you know if it's working when I'm back to work.